# "$@" expansion for user defined variables

Tags: shell, shell-script, quoting, variable, bourne-shell

I'm trying to get a (bourne shell) variable to expand like "**$@**" so it produces multiple words with some having preserved spaces. I've tried defining the variable in many different ways but still can't get it to work:

```
#!/bin/sh

n=\"one\ two\"\ three
for i in "$n"; do
echo $i
done
```

I want to define the variable so the script outputs `one two` first and then `three` next iteration, which is what you'd get if you replaced the quoted variable with "**$@**" and passed `'one two' three` as the arguments.

Is "**$@**" just magic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So bourne shell (IIRC) doesn't support arrays. You can still use "$@"

```
set -- "one two" three
for i in "${@}" ; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Outputs:

```
one two
three
```

Tested on AIX 7.1 bsh.

Comment: thanks, this does the trick. I guess this means "$@" is magic.

Comment: @user126144 Yes, it is. `"$@"` is the only thing that expands to several words despite being in double quotes. (Shells that support arrays have the same thing with `"${array_variable[@]}"`)

Comment: [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/23408#286350)  discusses arrays in bash, ksh, zsh, and yash,

Comment: Alternatively, `printf '%s\n' "$@"`